# socket.io client: how to determine if a handler is already installed

Tags: javascript, socket.io, handler

What happens if you call the 'on' method multiple times for the same function on a socket?  Does calling it multiple times simply overright the last registered function or does it use more resources?

If it is the later, then how do you determine if a handler is already registered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just looked at the socket in Firebug, there is a member called '_callbacks'.

It contains all the registered callbacks, so detecting if one is already registered is as simple as:

```
    if ( socket._callbacks[strHandlerName] == undefined ) {
    //Handler not present, install now
        socket.on(strHandlerName, function () { ... } );
    }
```

Thats it!

Comment: For me (using socket.io-client/engine.io-client on node.js), the handler names all have $ in front. ie. `socket._callbacks["$" + strHandlerName]`

Answer (score 1):

I am used to work with it this way.

```js
    var baseSocketOn = socket.on;

    socket.on = function() {
        var ignoreEvents = ['connect'] //maybe need it

        if (socket._callbacks !== undefined &&
            typeof socket._callbacks[arguments[0]] !== 'undefined' &&
            ignoreEvents.indexOf(arguments[0]) === -1) {
               return;
        }
        return baseSocketOn.apply(this, arguments)
    };
```

This is best practice